# presentViewController:animated:completion: always results in two instance of the presented view controller, is it a bug?

Tags: objective-c, ios, modalviewcontroller

I hooked into the presented view controller's init, loadView, viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear:, viewDidAppear:, viewDidUnload and dealloc method to log out relevant timing info.

But it was found that whether `presentModalViewController:animated:` or `presentViewController:animated:completion:` will result in two instance of the presented view controller and one of them will soonly be destroyed without anything appeared on screen(loadView and next method hasn't been fired yet).

Is it a bug or iOS' view controller transition just works like this?

Here is the log info, WDIMMindItemEditViewController is the presented view controller and WDIMMainScreenViewController is the presenting view controller:

> 2012-09-29 16:10:02.615 ideaCal[23450:707] < WDIMMindItemEditViewController: 0x2b5260> :editing view controller will initialize
>
> 2012-09-29 16:10:02.639 ideaCal[23450:707] < WDIMMindItemEditViewController: 0x2b5260> :editing view controller initialized
>
> 2012-09-29 16:10:02.641 ideaCal[23450:707] < WDIMMindItemEditViewController: 0x2b94d0> :editing view controller will initialize
>
> 2012-09-29 16:10:02.645 ideaCal[23450:707] < WDIMMindItemEditViewController: 0x2b94d0> :editing view controller initialized
>
> 2012-09-29 16:10:02.835 ideaCal[23450:707] < WDIMMainScreenViewController: 0x27c790> will present modal view controller: < WDIMMindItemEditViewController: 0x2b5260>
>
> 2012-09-29 16:10:02.841 ideaCal[23450:707] < WDIMMindItemEditViewController: 0x2b5260> :editing view controller load view
>
> 2012-09-29 16:10:02.910 ideaCal[23450:707] < WDIMMindItemEditViewController: 0x2b5260> :editing 
>   view controller has loaded view
>
> 2012-09-29 16:10:02.912 ideaCal[23450:707] < WDIMMindItemEditViewController: 0x2b5260> :editing view controller's view will appear
>
> 2012-09-29 16:10:03.297 ideaCal[23450:707] < WDIMMainScreenViewController: 0x27c790> will present modal view controller: < WDIMMindItemEditViewController: 0x2b94d0>
>
> 2012-09-29 16:10:03.302 ideaCal[23450:707] < WDIMMindItemEditViewController: 0x2b94d0> :editing view controller will dealloc
>
> 2012-09-29 16:10:03.340 ideaCal[23450:707] < WDIMMindItemEditViewController: 0x2b94d0> :editing view controller ended dealloc
>
> 2012-09-29 16:10:03.702 ideaCal[23450:707] < WDIMMindItemEditViewController: 0x2b5260> :editing view controller's view appeared
>
> 2012-09-29 16:10:05.434 ideaCal[23450:707] < WDIMMainScreenViewController: 0x27c790> ended present modal view controller: < WDIMMindItemEditViewController: 0x2b5260>

And here is my presenting code:

```
- (IBAction)slidingMenuGetPressed:(WZUICircularPagingControlViewSlidingMenu *)slidingMenu event:(UIEvent *)event
{
    WDIMEditViewController * editModalViewController = nil;
    if ([slidingMenu.identifier isEqualToString:NEW_MIND_ITEM]) {
        editModalViewController = [[WDIMMindItemEditViewController alloc] init];
    }
    if ([slidingMenu.identifier isEqualToString:NEW_PROJECT]) {
        editModalViewController = [[WDIMMindItemEditViewController alloc] init];
    }
    if ([slidingMenu.identifier isEqualToString:NEW_TAG]) {
        editModalViewController = [[WDIMTagEditViewController alloc] init];
    }

    dispatch_queue_t snapshotQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.WeZZardDesign.ScreenSnapshotQueue", NULL);
    dispatch_async(snapshotQueue, ^{
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, self.view.opaque, 0.0);
        [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        UIImage * snapshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            editModalViewController.backgroundImage = snapshot;
            NSManagedObjectContext * workingContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
            workingContext.parentContext = self.database.managedObjectContext;

            editModalViewController.preference = self.preference;
            editModalViewController.dataSource = self;
            editModalViewController.delegate = self;
            editModalViewController.workingContext = workingContext;

            NSLog(@"%@ will present modal view controller: %@", self, editModalViewController);
            [self presentViewController:editModalViewController animated:YES completion:^{
                NSLog(@"%@ ended present modal view controller: %@", self, editModalViewController);
            }];
        });
    });
    dispatch_release(snapshotQueue);
}
```

And I have got nothing changed in `presentModalViewController:animated:` and `presentViewController:animated:completion:` method.

Comment: Is looks as if two instances of `WDIMMindItemEditViewController` are initialized in `slidingMenuGetPressed`. Can it be that `NEW_MIND_ITEM` and `NEW_PROJECT` are identical strings? In that case two of the "if" blocks would be executed.

Comment: Yes, the `NEW_MIND_ITEM` and `NEW_PROJECT` are identical strings but they are not the same. And not only two instances of `WDIMMindItemEditViewController` were executed, but also `WDIMMainScreenViewController` presented all of them with one of them hasn't call the completion block. It's strange. I think I should create a clean project to rebuild the situation.

Comment: 1. `isEqualToString:` compares the string contents, not the pointer. So if NEW_MIND_ITEM and NEW_PROJECT are identical strings, then two "if" blocks will be executed. You should check this by setting a breakpoint in the debugger. - 2. "will present modal view controller ..." is shown twice in the NSLog output which means that `slidingMenuGetPressed` has been called twice.

Comment: Thanks! The problem solved! Your logic is stricter than mine.

Comment: You are welcome. I have added my comments as a formal answer, to that you can "accept" it by clicking on the check mark outline to the left of the answer. This will remove this question from the "unanswered questions" list. Thank you.

Comment: I've done it. And the real reason is `slidingMenuGetPressed` has been called twice. It was caused by programmatically sending sendActionsForEvents: method to a UIControl based class in a loop. And I haven't handle the control flow inside this loop correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments above it has become clear that `NEW_MIND_ITEM` and `NEW_PROJECT` are two strings having the same contents. Since  `isEqualToString` compares the contents, not the pointer, two "if" blocks are executed, creating two instances of `WDIMMindItemEditViewController`. Using different strings should solve the problem.